# passing CC/CFLAGS/LDFLAGS from Makefile to ./configure of Tk/Tcl

Tags: macos, makefile, tcl, configure, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to compile one library (xcrysden, based on Make file) which during its compilation execute ./configure of an external dependencies - Tk and Tcl 8.5 - and compiles them.

So, the structure is roughly like this:

The main Makefile:

```
...
cd external/src; make;
```

external dependencies (pre-)makefile (Tk):

```
include ../Make.sys
cd /unix
./configure
make
make install
```

Make.sys included by external makefile:

```
...
CFLAGS =...
CC     =...
```

The configure, obviously, produces another makefile in `/external/src/unix` to be used by Tk. 
In Tk documentation it is written:

`If you wish to specify a particular compiler, set the CC environment variable before calling configure. You can also specify CFLAGS prior to configure and they will be used during compilation.`

But from the resulting Makefile i definitely see that neither the defined compiler (CC) nor flags (CFLAGS) are used. Does it qualify as 'environment variable' when it is set in another make file?

I actually have problems compiling Tk, so i try to pass not only compiler but linking info 
`LDFLAGS = -L/opt/local/lib -lfontconfig` . 
I want to do it in a neat way (that is, modifying only Make.sys of the library dependent on Tk). But then i face the problem that not only don't i know how to pass `LDFLAGS` to Tk configure, but even `CC/CFLAGS` are not there. I'm not sure if this is specific to particular library (Tk) using ./configure or I misunderstand the general usage of ./configure.

p/s/ i'm compiling on OS-X using gnu compilers.

Comment: Are those variables being `export`ed?

Comment: no, they are not. Just defined as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variables you define in `../Make.sys` are currently local to the shell that processes the `include`; the `configure` and `make` are run in subprocesses and don't find out that you've got any preferences. The right thing to do is to add:

```
export CFLAGS CC
```

between the `include` and the call to `./configure`.

You could also put it inside `Make.sys`, or invoke `configure` as `CFLAGS=$CFLAGS CC=$CC ./configure`. You probably shouldn't set the values directly in the invocation of `make` though; setting the compiler can mean that different other flags are required as well.